# Android app crashes when downloaded from Google Play but works great in local dev - why?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm not sure if anyone can help with this but it is something really strange. I built an android app and tested it locally and everything works great. Then, I published it to the app store and it kept crashing.

The stack trace on google play showed:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
    at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.bbbb.SignedRequestsHelper.percentEncodeRfc3986(SignedRequestsHelper.java:120)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.bbbb.SignedRequestsHelper.sign(SignedRequestsHelper.java:63)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.SearchFragment$SearchAsyncTask.doInBackground(SearchFragment.java:385)
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.SearchFragment$SearchAsyncTask.doInBackground(SearchFragment.java:338)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 4 more
```

So it looks like there is something going on with my `SignedRequestsHelper.percentEncodeRfc3986()` method. A string is `null`. Note though, that this error did NOT happen when developing the app and testing it on different devices. It was only after uploading it to google play and downloading it from there that this error appeared.

So I looked in my SignedRequestHelper class which at the time looked like this:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class SignedRequestsHelper {
    private static final String UTF8_CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    private static final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";
    private static final String REQUEST_URI = "/onca/xml";
    private static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";

    // use xml-uk.amznxslt.com for xslt requests, or ecs.amazonaws.co.uk for others
    private String endpoint = "webservices.amazon.com"; // must be lowercase

    // change this so reads from properties file
    private String awsAccessKeyId = "xxxx";
    private String awsSecretKey = "xxx";

    private SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = null;
    private Mac mac = null;

    public SignedRequestsHelper() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        byte[] secretyKeyBytes = awsSecretKey.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
        secretKeySpec =
                new SecretKeySpec(secretyKeyBytes, HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(secretKeySpec);
    }

    public String sign(Map<String, String> params) {
        params.put("AWSAccessKeyId", awsAccessKeyId);
        params.put("Timestamp", timestamp());

        SortedMap<String, String> sortedParamMap =
                new TreeMap<String, String>(params);
        String canonicalQS = canonicalize(sortedParamMap);
        String toSign =
                REQUEST_METHOD + "\n"
                        + endpoint + "\n"
                        + REQUEST_URI + "\n"
                        + canonicalQS;

        String hmac = hmac(toSign);
        String sig = percentEncodeRfc3986(hmac);
        String url = "http://" + endpoint + REQUEST_URI + "?" +
                canonicalQS + "&Signature=" + sig;

        return url;
    }

    private String hmac(String stringToSign) {
        String signature = null;
        byte[] data;
        byte[] rawHmac;
        try {
            data = stringToSign.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
            rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data);
            Base64 encoder = new Base64();
            signature = new String(encoder.encode(rawHmac));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(UTF8_CHARSET + " is unsupported!", e);
        }
        return signature;
    }

    private String timestamp() {
        String timestamp = null;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        timestamp = dfm.format(cal.getTime());
        return timestamp;
    }

    private String canonicalize(SortedMap<String, String> sortedParamMap)
    {
        if (sortedParamMap.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iter =
                sortedParamMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> kvpair = iter.next();
            buffer.append(percentEncodeRfc3986(kvpair.getKey()));
            buffer.append("=");
            buffer.append(percentEncodeRfc3986(kvpair.getValue()));
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                buffer.append("&");
            }
        }
        String cannoical = buffer.toString();
        return cannoical;
    }

    private String percentEncodeRfc3986(String s) {
        String out;
        try {
            out = URLEncoder.encode(s, UTF8_CHARSET)
                    .replace("+", "%20")
                    .replace("*", "%2A")
                    .replace("%7E", "~");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            out = s;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

And I changed the `percentEncodeRfc3986()` method to look like this. Just removing the last two replace tags:

```
private String percentEncodeRfc3986(String s) {
        String out;
        try {
            out = URLEncoder.encode(s, UTF8_CHARSET)
                    .replace("+", "%20");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            out = s;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Then tested it locally: It works. And then published it to google play and downloaded it: It works.

**So everything is fine, but I am left here scratching my head as to why exactly this is working now**.

**It also makes me nervous because** code that worked perfectly on my emulator and test devices all of the sudden did not work when the app was uploaded to google play. This seems like a trivial matter... some extra replacing causing this error.

**Could someone help me understand what is happening here?** Or at least why sometimes code on an app published to google play might not work or execute exactly like in local dev?

EDIT:
My build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you change your build version to release in Android Studio and run it, does it crash?

Comment: @vguzzi how does one actually do that?

Comment: In Android Studio look at the bottom left of the window for a tab called Build Versions, click it then change where it says debug to release, then run your application like normal.

Comment: @vguzzi Getting a "app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog." error when I do that. Even though I did Build->Generate Signed APK like normal.

Comment: Could you paste your build.gradle code under buildTypes please.

Comment: Could you place `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` into the release object and see if you can then run it.

Comment: @vguzzi Errors when I do that: "Error:(18, 0) Could not find property 'release' on SigningConfig container."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tests, I determined that the reason I got that error was because I did not update my SDK and other updates in Android Studio when I initially published my App. Because after I updated I reverted my code to the way it was when it was crashing and everything worked fine - which makes sense because I really saw absolutely no reason for my code to not be working.

So yeah lesson here is make sure all of your SDK tools and Android Studio are all up to date before signing the release version of your app!

Answer (score 0):

Alright your missing a signing certificate, this is only needed for release builds which is why you didn't experience it when debugging.

To sign your Android app you'll have to generate a keystore and store that inside your application. You'll then have to add a few more lines of code in your build.gradle file telling it what your keystore is named, and it's passwords. The end result will look something like this:

```
SigningConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../keystore.jks")
            storePassword "7uSFX****"
            keyAlias "app"
            keyPassword "GQ****"
        }
    }
```

Then specifying this line of code inside your buildTypes will correctly sign your application.

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

Please note it is best practice to also include a debug buildType so when you are debugging your application you don't have to sign it. Something like this (note it's missing `signingConfig signingConfigs.release`):

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".debug"
}
```

Please follow a guide to generate a keystore for your app it's relatively easy. I will edit this post with details on how to do it at a later date.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I did sign my app though before publishing it on google play. In fact, google play won't let you publish an app unless it is signed. I went to Build -> Generate Signed APK. This made a `app-release.apk` file in `MyApp/app` directory. Then I uploaded that exact .apk file to google play. The app worked in all respects except when using a search function in my app. Using that search function generated the error I posted in my question.

Unless I am misunderstanding something, thus your answer does not seem to be the issue for me...